# How to trigger onPerformSync when a certain variable value changes

Tags: java, android, android-syncadapter

I'm developing an app which contains updating profile picture. What I'm doing is the following: I'm storing the user's profile URI using `sharedPreferences`, and when the user updates their profile image, I want to run `syncAdapter` to sync the profile pic to the server. However, syncing works fine when using refresh button in the settings, but it is never triggered when using `requestSync`.

I've tried using requestSync and using the flags `SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL` and `SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED`, but id didn't work. Here's the code I tried:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    switch(requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID:
            selectedImage = null;
            try {
                selectedImage = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(getContext(), resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Glide.with( this )
                    .load( selectedImage )
                    .into( imageButton );

            SharedPreferences login = getContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login.edit();
            String exProfileUri = login.getString( USER_PROFILE_PIC,USER_PROFILE_PIC );
            Log.i( "exprofile","  " + exProfileUri );
          //If user picks an image for their profile
            if(selectedImage != null) {
                editor.putString( USER_PROFILE_PIC,  
                selectedImage.toString());
                editor.apply();
                //We should then trigger SyncAdapter
                syncOnProfileImageChanged();
                
                 }
         
            }
            else if(selectedImage == null && exProfileUri != null){

                    editor.putString( USER_PROFILE_PIC, exProfileUri);
                    editor.apply();
            }

            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that should triggers onPerformSync:
public void SyncProfileImage(){

```
mAccount  = new Account(
            ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);


    Log.i( "exprofile","New profile image should be synced now...  "  + mAccount );
    Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle(  );
    settingsBundle.putBoolean( ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    settingsBundle.putBoolean( ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true );
    settingsBundle.putBoolean( ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true );
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable( mAccount, AUTHORITY, 1 );
    if(ContentResolver.isSyncPending( mAccount, AUTHORITY )||
            ContentResolver.isSyncActive( mAccount, AUTHORITY )){
        Log.i( "ContentResolver","SyncPending, calceling" );
        ContentResolver.cancelSync( mAccount, AUTHORITY );

    }
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable( mAccount, AUTHORITY, 1 );
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically( mAccount,AUTHORITY, true );
    ContentResolver.requestSync( mAccount, AUTHORITY,  settingsBundle);
}
```

I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I was wrong about the Auothority, it wasn't the same as the one declared in the sync adapter xml.